Concurrency safety during frame updates in Swift
I have a method named render that's called on every frame to draw something on screen using Metal. It is rendering some array of points stored inside the class. However, I occasionally need to update this array of points. I'm struggling to come up with a solution that could update these points in a concurrency safe manner.
Namely, when render is attempting to access this array, another thread could be updating it, leading to a crash. Additionally, render is synchronous and cannot block on or await the update. This seems like a commonly occurring concurrency problem so I'm seeking help here to see what solutions there are.
To generalize the problem -- there's some synchronous function that's called very frequently, it needs access to a piece of data that could be updated by another thread. I do have control over both the render method and the "other" thread that does the update. How can I prevent a race condition from crashing the app? (it just has to not crash, there's no data "correctness" considerations)

One possible solution I hypothesized is using atomics I'm not exactly sure how it could be done, especially in Swift (don't think Swift has atomics?)

EDIT:
I'll attempt to add some more context here but it may be difficult to add a MRE considering that apart of what I'm implementing is tucked away in a private repo that I don't have access to.
In short, I'm attempting to implement a MapBox custom layer following this example. The details of this particular render function in the example is irrelevant since my render method needs to do something completely different, but it would look something like this in pseudocode:
class MyCustomLayer: NSObject, CustomLayerHost {
    var locationData: [CLLocation] = []
    
    func render(...) {
        // calculate the viewport from the parameters
        let viewport = ...
        if viewport.fitSomeCondition {
            // fetch new location data. This can't block and needs to happen async
            fetchLocationDataFromServer(viewport: viewport)
            // need to somehow update the locationData
        }
        
        // render locationData
    }
}

Here, locationData is an array of longitudes and latitudes, and render is apart of the CustomLayerHost protocol from the MapBox iOS SDK. Source code for how CustomLayerHost is handled is not available to the public but here is the header declaration:
/**
 * Render the layer. This method is called once per frame.
 *
 * This method is called if underlying map rendering backend uses Metal graphic API.
 *
 * @param The `parameters` that define the current camera position.
 * @param The MTLCommandBuffer used to render all map layers.
 * Use to create new command encoders. Do not submit as there could be map
 * layers following this custom layer in style's layer list and those won't get
 * to be encoded.
 * @param The MTLRenderPassDescriptor that defines rendering map to view drawable.
 *
 */
- (void)render:(nonnull MBMCustomLayerRenderParameters *)parameters
mtlCommandBuffer:(nonnull id<MTLCommandBuffer>)mtlCommandBuffer
mtlRenderPassDescriptor:(nonnull MTLRenderPassDescriptor *)mtlRenderPassDescriptor;

I understand that this isn't a MRE but I hope this helps in making the question clearer.

@Rob I added more context. It's not exactly a MRE but I hope it could help. Thanks

So, you’re just trying to eliminate data race for locationData? I.e., render may be rendering that locationData and the asynchronous network requests might be updating locationData? Seems like a simple locking pattern would be adequate.

My understanding of locks led me to believe that they're relatively slow and undesirable for high performance scenarios like frame updates. But I may be wrong?

No locks are, nowadays, very fast, especially the unfair lock. Even NSLock is pretty fast. Reader-writer is a bit slower. GCD serial queue is even slower. Semaphores are even much slower. Benchmark it with optimized (non-debug) build if you are concerned. But I would shy away from Swift Atomics, or the equivalent, as those are designed for a slightly different scenario. Locks will be plenty fast for you.

If you are just trying to prevent the data race for locationData, I would advise adding some synchronization. For example, in high-performance scenarios, we might lean towards a lock-based synchronization:
import os.lock

class MyCustomLayer: NSObject, CustomLayerHost {
    private let lock = OSAllocatedUnfairLock()    // or `NSLock` would likely be fine, too
    private var _locationData: [CLLocation] = []
    
    // synchronized access to _locationData
    
    private var locationData: [CLLocation] {
        get { lock.withLock { _locationData } }
        set { lock.withLock { _locationData = newValue } }
    }

    func render() {
        // calculate the viewport from the parameters
        let viewport = …

        // fetch locations if necessary
        if viewport.fitSomeCondition {
            fetchLocationDataFromServer()
        }

        // in the meantime, fetch copy of `locationData`
        let locationsToRender = locationData

        // now render `locationsToRender`, our local copy
        …
    }
    
    func fetchLocationDataFromServer() {
        let request: URLRequest = …
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
            locationData = …
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

There are a lot of synchronization patterns (GCD serial queues, actors, etc.), but for something that needs to run as frequently as frame-by-frame, I might lean towards a more performant synchronization mechanism, namely unfair locks, shown above.
Note, we want to minimize the number of synchronizations, so, I would avoid referencing locationData repeatedly within render, but rather do it once, assigning it to a local variable.
Also, it is beyond the scope of the question, but think long and hard about fitSomeCondition, and make sure you avoid redundant or concurrent network requests.

For what it is worth, I might consider moving this lock-based synchronization to its own property wrapper:
@propertyWrapper
class Synchronized<T> {
    private let lock = OSAllocatedUnfairLock()
    private var _wrappedValue: T
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { lock.withLock { _wrappedValue } }
        set { lock.withLock { _wrappedValue = newValue } }
    }
    
    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        _wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}

And that simplifies MyCustomLayer:
class MyCustomLayer: NSObject, CustomLayerHost {
    @Synchronized private var locationData: [CLLocation] = []
    
    func render() {
        let viewport = …

        if viewport.fitSomeCondition {
            fetchLocationDataFromServer()
        }

        // fetch copy of `locationData`
        let locationsToRender = locationData

        // now render `locationsToRender`, our local copy
        …
    }
    
    func fetchLocationDataFromServer() {
        let request: URLRequest = …
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
            locationData = …
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}


Thank you. I didn't know about the performance difference between OSAllocatedUnfairLock and NSLock. Very helpful :)
